# Error Message: "Missing number, treated as zero."

Tags: subcaption, includegraphics

searched a lot around to fix this issue, usually it only takes a few seconds but now I have no luck. LaTeX puts out this error message mentioned above, here's my code:

```
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}

...


\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[h]
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{kurzpass.png}
\caption[]{Filterkurve eines typischen Kurzpassfilters\footnotemark}
\label{fig:kurzpass}
\end{subfigure}
%
```

Error Message:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
 
                   \unhbox 
l.137 \includegraphics
                      [scale=0.7]{kurzpass.png}
? X
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subfigure` environment provided by [`subcaption`](//ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) has the following format

```
\begin{subfigure}[<pos>]{<width>}
  % ...your subfigure here...
\end{subfigure}
```

While the `<pos>`ition is optional, you have to specify a `<width>` for the subfigure. You've neglected to do that.

To fix this, add a length, for example

```
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
  % ...your subfigure here...
\end{subfigure}
```

Comment: Ah okay, Merci! But after doing this there is always a message like

> Overfull \hbox (2.37161pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 137--138

or

> Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 136--147

i do not get it.